# bootstrap how to appear scrollbar when reduce browser's size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I'm using bootstrap 3.0 on the layout of my page.
My HTML is something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I tried to reduce my browser's size (IE/Chrome/Firefox). they shrink and overlapped. What I want is that having an horizontal scrollbar appear when the browser doesn't have enough width, which bootstrap container has a fixed width of 1170px.
What css would I apply to achieve this goal?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can add fixed width to body tag, or wrap your code to outer wrapper

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

**DEMO** *(updated)*

http://jsfiddle.net/R5PXH/480/

Comment: Hi, it does appear a horizontal scrollbar. However, the container layout got changed.  bootstrap have a margin and padding of 15px on the container so that container at the center of the page. when I add wrapper, the container go left of the whole screen. any fix on this?

Comment: Yes, there are to solutions: 1) Change wrapper css - width: 1200px ('cause Boostrap .container add margin left and right 15px)   2) override .container styles, so add custom css - .container {margin-left: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important}    I think the best one is **1)**

Comment: I tried both solution. They didn't make the container to center..for solution 1, what about user open it with a large screen? the 1200px would cause unbalance white space at left and right side, am I correct?

Comment: oh, yes, i forgot that try again first one, but add this rules `.wrapper {width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: that works well. I have another problem, when I reduce the screen, the horizontal scrollbar appears. how ever, the layout of the content changes. for example if I have two .col-md-6 inside a .row. they will become two row if the screen is very small. how would I fix those things?

Comment: You are using Bootstrap - i.e. Mobile-first framework. If you want to use only elements from Bootstrap, without mobile-responsive features, you should customize your css file here - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/